# Diophantine Equations involving cubes

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm doing some number theory research and I came across these two Diophantine equations (created under my own transformations):

$$y^3 = ax^3 + bx$$ (where $a$ and $b$ are parameters)

$$z^3 = x^2 + xy$$

Has anyone seen these before? I'm trying to find references or links for these but I'm having trouble. I don't need to solve both, just one. I would like to solve them over the integers and (eventually) prove that there are only a finite number of solutions.

Edit: $x,y,z$ must be $> 1$.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions $(x,y,z)=(x,x^{3k-1}-x,x^k)$ for the Diophantine equation $z^3=x^2+xy$.

Comment: I've added a new post. Thanks.

Comment: See Mordell, Diophantine Equations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. This is very very close to what I want. But I have a linear term as well, unfortunately. I might be able to use similar strategies that were used in Mordell's equation...